# What is the biological pathway for the biodegradation of DDT (pesticide)?

Tags: microbiology, metabolism, mycology, environment, pesticide

There are various micro organisms which can degrade DDT. Which micro organism is most frequently used for biodegradation of DDT and what is the metabolic pathway by which DDT is degraded?